# Jenkins - install envinject plugin

Tags: jenkins

Im trying to install envinject plugin in Jenkins but could not find the plugin.

When I search in the plugin list, I get the following -

```
Environment File Plugin

This plugin enables you to set environment variables via a file. The file's format must be the standard Java property file format. Superseded by the [EnvInject Plugin]? The property file is always retrieved from the file system of the Jenkins master node, even in distributed setups with slave nodes. You can reference already defined environment variables both to specify the path to the property file, in a job's configuration, and in property values, in the property file.



Shared Objects Plugin


This plugin makes it possible to share objects (script file, source file, tool installation, ...) from an environment in Jenkins and manage dynamically these objects through environment variables with the [JENKINS:EnvInject Plugin] during the job build.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Plugin list ("Available Plugins" tab for you if you haven't installed it yet), it is listed as:

```
Environment Injector Plugin  -> This plugin makes it possible to set an environment for the builds.
```

while the link to the plugin page is: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin